# Использование переменных в Python 3 с Sqlite

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.5

Как заменить еденицы на переменные?

```
def inf(fn, name, price):
    import sqlite3
    from datetime import datetime
    dat, price, name = str(datetime.now())[0:19], int(price.replace(' ', '')), name.replace('&quot;', '"').replace('&#34;', '"').replace('&amp;','&')
    log = open('log.txt','a')
    conn = sqlite3.connect('pmonitor.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names2 WHERE name = '1'")
    if c.fetchall() != [(0,)]:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO prices VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (fn, dat, name, price))
    else:
        c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names1 WHERE name = '1'")
        if c.fetchall() != [(0,)]:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO prices VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (fn, dat, name, price))
        else:
            c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stopnames WHERE name = '1'")
            if c.fetchall() == [(0,)]:
                log.write(name+'\t')
    conn.commit()
    log.close()
```

Comment: Используйте оформление кода с помощью отступа в 4 пробела. Боюсь править сам: это может нарушить смысл python-кода.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю то это должно быть так([описание execute](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)):

```
c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stopnames WHERE name = ?", (name,))
```

Или так

```
c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stopnames WHERE name = :name", {"name": name})
```